# how to add video timer in android

Tags: android, video, timer

i am new in android. i am developing an application where i record a video and see the time of its recording.i cant add the timer part.can anyone help me out..
my camera recording part i s as follows---

```
 myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(recording){
                // stop recording and release camera
                mediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object

                //Exit after saved
                finish();
            }else{

                //Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
                releaseCamera();

                if(!prepareMediaRecorder()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                            "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }

                mediaRecorder.start();
                recording = true;
                myButton.setText("STOP");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following link. Start timer on recording press `button` and stop it on recording stop `button`.

[Android Timer Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Timer is not part of the native recorder, you have to implement it yourself. If you need it only for the recording process just add a timer view. If you want to see the timer in the final result ask me how, it is more complicate to implement.